# Custom font in Blackberry 10

Tags: blackberry-10

Hi I am new to blackberry10 platform and I am stuck with adding custom font in blackberry10. Please anybody tell me how to add custom font in blackberry 10.

Answer (score 1):

According to BlackBerry, custom fonts can only be added using an OpenGL project. There is a sample project bundled with the SDK (sdkdir\target_10_0_9_2318\qnx6\usr\share\samples\ndk\GoodCitizen).

In the main.c file, change the path of the font sent to the bbutil_load_font function to that of your font file.

Comment: but i am searching for loading font from cascades

Comment: They are adding to future releases for the cascades I thin so,check the https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/download/roadmap/

Comment: where is that written, that you can only add it using OpenGL?

Comment: @desgraci BlackBerry informed me. This may no longer be the case though

Answer (score 0):

We can add custom fonts in QML.
link below provides a sample for the same :

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__fontfacerule.html
Download the font file (ttf) you need and that can be packaged in the assets folder.

Adding a custom font in C++ is not supported as of now.